# How to highlight a hover period for another date in custom DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a custom selection period in a React app. When I select two dates in it, the picker closes and the data table is updated. These two dates are stored in a state like this:
`const [start, end] = useState(null);`

I need to do the following: when the first date of the period (`start`) was selected, the user moves the cursor to another date in DatePicker. If the cursor is on a different date (not clicked), all dates from the start to the hover date should be grayed out in the background.

I am adding CSS style for one covered date:

```
&:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

How can I do this for the entire period?

For example: I select May 6 as the beginning of the period, and I hover over May 9. All dates in the period (May 6, 7, 8, 9) must be gray

Answer (score 0):

So you have start and end data. That is mean you can calculate or add some condition to send props like "cellInRange". I'm using css in js, so there is ability to send some params, then you can check

```
const SomeElement = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.cellInRange ? "blue" : "white"};
`
```

Something like this.

Comment: Try styled-components

Comment: The start and end of the period are saved after clicking on them. The highlight should work when the start of the period is selected (set to state), but the end of the period is not selected (not set to state). So I have only the start of the period in the state